# Adding subtitle tracks in android media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Hi I am new in Android development. I want to add subtitle to media player in my android application. I have searched and found a method i.e. addTimedTextSource(...)
but it gives the error 
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.media.MediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_view);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
//        vw = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_intent);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
        Log.d("File path ::::::::::::::::::",path);

        try {
            mp.setDataSource("file://"+path);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
        String mimeType = getMimeType("file://mnt/sdcard/BarbieGirl.srt");
//      mp.selectTrack(index);
        try {
            mp.addTimedTextSource(path, mimeType);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

can anyone please tell me how to use this or any idea about how can I display the subtitle tracks in android.

thanks

Comment: Not the solution just a note: use MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP instead of getMimeType()

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting that error, it is probably because you are running this code on a device less than SDK 16 (Jelly Bean).  You should wrap it in an SDK gate:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
   mp.addTimedTextSource(...
}
```